# Связь по смыслу двух предложений

Tags: смысл, тавтология

Есть два предложения, например:

***Глеб пнул со злости камушек, и тот улетел в реку. В этот момент к нему пришло мимолетное воспоминание, как он в детстве с отцом плавал по этой самой реке на лодке.***

Итак, понять смысл сего возможно в двух ответвлениях - тут либо Глебу пришло воспоминание, либо камню. И вот второе, ясное дело, неверно. Можно, конечно, добавить, уточнить, что воспоминание пришло к парню/Глебу, но а если без этого? Как перефразировать/переделать два предложения, не добавляя при этом повтор имени или запись признака (что он парень) истинного хозяина воспоминания?

Честно признаюсь, что вопрос больше "от балды", **НО**, в оправдание своё скажу, что с подобным сталкивалась при написании часто и всегда приходилось эти предложения обходить как-то закоулками, чтобы и мысли у читателей (и меня самой) не возникло, что предмет вспомнил/почувствовал что-то (и нет, настолько фэнтези я не пишу - предметы там остаются предметами). А закоулками я это обхожу, так как повторения "Глеб, парень, Глеб" и так далее я вижу тавтологией.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С точки зрения семантики здесь всё ясно, **но стилистическая неточность присутствует.** Предложение в таких случаях желательно редактировать (одно и то же содержание можно выразить в разных формах, и не факт, что вы используете самую удачную):

(1) Глеб пнул со злости камушек, и тот улетел в реку. **В этот момент вдруг вспомнилось**, как он в детстве с отцом плавал по этой самой реке на лодке.

(2) Глеб пнул со злости камушек, и тот улетел в реку. **Вспомнилось мимолетом,** как он в детстве с отцом плавал по этой самой реке на лодке.

(3) Глеб пнул со злости камушек, и тот улетел в реку. В этот момент **мимолетом вспомнилось,** как он в детстве с отцом плавал по этой самой реке на лодке.

Примечание

***В этот момент к нему пришло мимолетное воспоминание*** ― желательно эту мысль выразить короче.

Answer (score 2):

Тут ларчик просто открывается: камень не может посетить воспоминание о детском плавании с отцом. То есть нет необходимости выяснять или объяснять, кто на ком стоял.

Вот если бы Глебушко пнул, к примеру, Иванушку, тогда да, куды ж деться. Надо вдаться в пояснения, кто именно (во избежание повтора обычно пишут "последнему", это ежели Иванушка второй раз умудрился войти в одну и ту же реку) осенён воспоминаньем.